# Site_Type returns "main_site" for meta.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, api-v2, sites

For Meta Stack Overflow, the 2.0/sites endpoint returns "main_site" rather than "meta_site". All other site_type for other stackexchange sites return correctly.

URL: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/sites?filter=!3x9D0xtBGnDvaejbR

Expected (partial) response:

```
...
{
"site_type": "meta_site",
"name": "Meta Stack Overflow",
"api_site_parameter": "meta.stackoverflow",
"site_url": "http://meta.stackoverflow.com"
},
...
```

Actual (partial) response:

```
...
{
"site_type": "main_site",
"name": "Meta Stack Overflow",
"api_site_parameter": "meta.stackoverflow",
"site_url": "http://meta.stackoverflow.com"
},
...
```

Apologies if this is intended behaviour - if so, the name is very misleading! I searched but didn't find any reference to it in existing bugs / questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow is a main site in the sense that it doesn't have any linking between it and Stack Overflow.

Separate rep system, separate user account, distinct ids, etc. etc.

It is *weird*, but it is accurate.  The whole arrangement is a historical accident, with Meta Stack Overflow predating the entire SE 2.0 system.